# Casting through reflection from simple type to complex type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting

I'm looking into casting, in this case, from Int32 to a more complex type.

Here's how you would get an instance of this complex type through normal means:

```
OptionSetValue option = new OptionSetValue(90001111); //int value...
```

Now, I am trying to do this via reflection. Here is my method doing it:

```
    public static void SetValue(object entity, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType;
            object safeValue = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, t); //Line where the exception is thrown...
            pi.SetValue(entity, safeValue, null);

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        return;
    }
```

And here's how I use it:

```
SetValue(entity, "reason", 90001111);
```

"reason" is a property of entity of type OptionSetValue. When using it like this, on the above noted line, I will get this exception:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'.
```

Is it because the two properties come from different assemblies ? If so, it is even possible to do what I am after ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast an integer to that class. Use the following code instead:

```
object safeValue = (value == null) ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(t, value);
```

What the above code does is creating a new instance of `OptionSetValue` and passing your value to its constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered your own question.

> "reason" is a property of entity of type OptionSetValue

If that's the case, then `pi.PropertyType` is `OptionSetValue`, and

```
Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType;
```

returns `OptionSetValue`.

The invalid cast comes from `Convert.ChangeType(value, t)`. Since a converter for `OptionSetValue` hasn't been registered, the runtime doesn't know how to do this conversion. Also see this MSDN article on [how to register a `TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) if you are interested in going that route.

See Eve's use of `Activator.CreateInstance` to see how to overcome this issue.